# Go channels, tcp/ip portmap not returning all open ports

Tags: go

I have been learning Golang to move all my penetration testing tools to it. Since I like to write my own tools this is a perfect way to learn a new language. In this particular case I think something is wrong with the way I am using channels. I know for a fact that is not finishing the port mapping because the other tools I use that I wrote on ruby are finding all the open ports but my golang tool is not. Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Are channels the right way to go about doing this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func portScan(TargetToScan string, PortStart int, PortEnd int, openPorts []int) []int {
    activeThreads := 0
    doneChannel := make(chan bool)

    for port := PortStart; port <= PortEnd; port++ {
        go grabBanner(TargetToScan, port, doneChannel)
        activeThreads++
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for activeThreads > 0 {
        <-doneChannel
        activeThreads--
    }
    return openPorts
}

func grabBanner(ip string, port int, doneChannel chan bool) {
    connection, err := net.DialTimeout(
        "tcp",
        ip+":"+strconv.Itoa(port),
        time.Second*10)
    if err != nil {
        doneChannel <- true
        return
    }
    // append open port to slice
    openPorts = append(openPorts, port)

    fmt.Printf("+ Port %d: Open\n", port)
    // See if server offers anything to read
    buffer := make([]byte, 4096)
    connection.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 5))
    // Set timeout
    numBytesRead, err := connection.Read(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        doneChannel <- true
        return
    }
    log.Printf("+ Banner of port %d\n%s\n", port,
        buffer[0:numBytesRead])
    // here we add to map port and banner
    targetPorts[port] = string(buffer[0:numBytesRead])

    doneChannel <- true
    return
}
```

Note: seems to find the first bunch ports but not the ones that are above a hight number example 8080  but it usually does get 80 and 443...
So I suspect something is timing out, or something odd is going on.

There are lots of bad hacks of code, mostly because I'm learning and searching a lot in how to do things, so feel free to give tips and even changes/pull requests. thanks

Comment: links are ok to use but not exclusively. Links can be unreliable.
Please post your code directly into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few problems. In `grabBanner` you appear to be referencing `openPorts` but it is not defined anywhere. You're probably referencing a global variable and this append operation is not going to be thread safe. In addition to your thread safety issues you also are likely exhausting file descriptor limits. Perhaps you should limit the amount of concurrent work by doing something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(portScan("127.0.0.1", 1, 65535))
}

// startBanner spins up a handful of async workers
func startBannerGrabbers(num int, target string, portsIn <-chan int) <-chan int {
    portsOut := make(chan int)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(num)

    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        go func() {
            for p := range portsIn {
                if grabBanner(target, p) {
                    portsOut <- p
                }
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(portsOut)
    }()

    return portsOut

}

func portScan(targetToScan string, portStart int, portEnd int) []int {
    ports := make(chan int)

    go func() {
        for port := portStart; port <= portEnd; port++ {
            ports <- port
        }
        close(ports)
    }()

    resultChan := startBannerGrabbers(16, targetToScan, ports)

    var openPorts []int
    for port := range resultChan {
        openPorts = append(openPorts, port)
    }

    return openPorts
}

var targetPorts = make(map[int]string)

func grabBanner(ip string, port int) bool {
    connection, err := net.DialTimeout(
        "tcp",
        ip+":"+strconv.Itoa(port),
        time.Second*20)

    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    defer connection.Close() // you should close this!

    buffer := make([]byte, 4096)
    connection.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * 5))
    numBytesRead, err := connection.Read(buffer)

    if err != nil {
        return true
    }

    // here we add to map port and banner
    // ******* MAPS ARE NOT SAFE FOR CONCURRENT WRITERS ******
    // *******************  DO NOT DO THIS *******************
    targetPorts[port] = string(buffer[0:numBytesRead])

    return true
}
```

Your usage of `var open bool` and constantly setting it, then returning it is both unnecessary and non-idiomatic. In addition, checking `if someBoolVar != false` is a non-idiomatic and verbose way of writing `if someBoolVar`.

Additionally maps are not safe for concurrent access but your grabBanner function is writing to map from many go routines in a concurrent fashion. *Please stop mutating global state inside of functions*. Return values instead.

Here's an updated explanation of what's going on. First we make a channel that we will push port numbers onto for our workers to process. Then we start a go-routine that will write ports in the range onto that channel as fast as it can. Once we've written every port available onto that channel we close the channel so that our readers will be able to exit.

Then we call a method that starts a configurable number of `bannerGrabber` workers. We pass the ip address and the channel to read candidate port numbers off of. This function spawns `num` goroutines, each ranging over the `portsIn` channel that was passed, calls the `grab banner` function and then pushes the port onto the outbound channel if it was successful. Finally, we start one more go routine that waits on the `sync.WaitGroup` to finish so we can close the outgoing (result) channel once all of the workers are done.

Back in the `portScan` function We receive the outbound channel as the return value from the `startBannerGrabbers` function. We then range over the result channel that was returned to us, append all the open ports to the list and then return the result.

I also changed some stylistic things, such as down-casing your function argument names.

At risk of sounding like a broken record I am going to emphasize the following again. **Stop mutating global state**. Instead of setting `targetPorts` you should accumulate these values in a concurrency-safe manner and return them to the caller for use. It appears your usage of globals in this case is ill-thought out a mixture of convenience and not having thought about how to solve the problem without globals.

Comment: they thanks ! I apreciate it, I am on the move now will review as soon I get back to my apt, my original link pointed to github for a reason.. everything is referenced on main.go  if you want to take a look there.
will get back to you when Im home see if your solution works, about the style I was following the tips from vim-go. thanks again  PS: here is the github with the whole project  https://github.com/ReK2Fernandez/GoEnumerator/blob/master/portscan.go

Comment: No problem. I see the main file now. I would strongly urge you to reconsider the excessive use of globals. It doesn't seem necessary and you've got functions in different files both shadowing and setting globals defined in other files. If you try to adapt me code, be careful.

Comment: thanks, yeah I will refactor everything as soon I get it working as I want. I implemented your code "somehow" lol  so is working as before with the changes but still not getting the upper ports.. max I get is  4444 etc never gets to the 50K something.
https://github.com/ReK2Fernandez/GoEnumerator/blob/master/portscan.go  changes are commited.

Comment: So I tested out your code and I suspect you're hitting the same issue I am. Your'e exceeding your open file limit trying to open ~65000 connections at once. You should limit the number of goroutines actually connecting.

Comment: @cfernandezlinux I've redone the answer. Please take my advice to heart. You have some serious design issues, almost entirely rooted in mutation of global state. In addition to that unbounded concurrency and failure to clean up resources after use also cause many problems. I would strongly suggest you read the documentation for the APIs you are using, especially when they involve system/os level resources.

Comment: hey thanks so much, really I love that you are not just giving me a solution but also style and software tips, as you can see I am not a software engineer..  I can code but I learn myself and come from the systems/network/hacking side of tech, so any tips and pointing me in the right direction is always much apreciated.. I think this is one of the best ever help I got when it comes to coding. as you can see in my code is mostly hacks and figuring things out on my own. so the fact that you are giving me such much good information is amazing. will test and refactor if portmap works. tx